# WPF Data grid Text Ellipsis Not working

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, ellipsis

I have a column with long user comments. I load it using following code...

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Message"
                       Binding="{Binding UserMessage, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       CanUserSort="True">
    <my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
               <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                       Value="NoWrap" />
               <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
                       Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>                                    
               <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                       Value="{Binding Path=UserMessage, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</my:DataGridTextColumn>
```

But the ellipsis wont work. The column continues to display long text of data. Also when I set the width of the textblock explicitly to some value then the ellipsis work fine but when I resize my column it wont show any more text in it.

Isnt there a starighforward way to do this?

Thx
Vinit Sankhe.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting widths on your columns that only need static widths.  On this column you set the width to "*"

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Message"
                       Binding="{Binding UserMessage, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       CanUserSort="True"
                       Width="*">
    <my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
               <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                       Value="NoWrap" />
               <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
                       Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>                                    
               <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                       Value="{Binding Path=UserMessage, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</my:DataGridTextColumn>
```

I found your question by Googling your question.  I took your code and just added widths to my columns (except for a "Title" column) and was able to have it place the ellipsis correctly.  I also added a MinWidth just to make sure that when the window is resized the column isn't squished to nothing.