# . How To Truncate DataGridTextColumn LongText With "..."

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, truncate

. I Need Truncate The DataGridTextColumn LongTexts With "..." On The Right, But i Have No Idea Of "How To Make It" Like This:

[What i Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FScsc.png)

. ANd Not Like Are Now:

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ezH.png)

This Is My DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="Musics" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCheckBox}">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox/>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>-->
            <DataGridTextColumn/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Título" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" MaxWidth="400" SortDirection="Ascending" SortMemberPath="Title"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duração" Binding="{Binding Path=Duration}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlign}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4 8 2 8"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Intérprete" Binding="{Binding Path=Artist}" MaxWidth="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Álbum" Binding="{Binding Path=Album}" MaxWidth="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Género" Binding="{Binding Path=Genre}" MaxWidth="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Classificação" Binding="{Binding Path=Classification}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlign}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4 8 2 8"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reproduções" Binding="{Binding Path=TimesPlayed}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlign}" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4 8 2 8"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Reproduzir"/>
                <MenuItem Header="A seguir"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Informações"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Eliminar"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Abrir no explorador"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Adicionar a Playlis">
                    <MenuItem Header="Mais reproduzidas"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks, And Waiting For Your Help :

Comment: Would this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510029/wpf-data-grid-text-ellipsis-not-working ticket me of any value to you?

Comment: . Very Thanks Bro, Thats Help :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ElementStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleKey" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleKey}" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: . Not Working Bro, Thats What i Have Done: `code`<Style x:Key="rightAlign" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </Style>`code`

Comment: @EleandroDuzentos: how do you apply this style?

Comment: . Just a Second, i Think Is My Fail

Comment: . Very Thanks Bro, Thats Help Too Much :D